# Showing $\frac{\delta V_{out}}{V_{out}}=\frac{\delta R_2}{R_2} \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}$

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, differentiation

Consider a voltage divider with $V_{out}=V_{in} \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}$. Show that for a small change in $R_2$, the voltage divider equation is:
$\frac{\delta V_{out}}{V_{out}}=\frac{\delta R_2}{R_2} \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}$. I've been trying to get to that for awhile, but I'm a little confused on how to exactly set UP the problem, along with solving it. I tried both of the following, and ended up with an unsimplify-able expression in both cases that wasn't the one i was looking for.

Attempt One:
$
\delta V_{out}+{V_{out}}=\frac{R_2+\delta R_2}{R_1+R_2+\delta R_2}
$
and Attempt Two:
$
\delta V_{out}+{V_{out}}=\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}+\frac{\delta R_2}{R_1+\delta R_2}
$
Neither worked. WMy question seems to be mainly HOW to set up the equation to manipulate and then find the solution. I don't believe my algebra had an error, but it could have. So, any suggestions, without solving it for me on how to set this up?
Thanks.
If the answer is in my math, not method, I will post the work once someone helps me understand/confirms how to set up the problem correctly.
attempting the comment below

$
\dfrac{dV_{out}}{dR_2} = ( \frac{dR_2}{dR_2}\frac{1}{R_1+R_2} + R_2\frac{d(R_1+R_2)}{dR_2}) V_{in} = 
$
which appeas to be correct, but how to change the R_2 in the numerator to the top?

Comment: Maybe differentiate $V_{out}$ wrt $R_2$ ? This is not really a valid Physics SE question.

Comment: Is there a better place I may propose my question ? perhaps math stackexchange?

Comment: my apologies if it isn't proper, I will delete it if it isn't.

Comment: Perhaps, but to be honest, it's a pretty simple problem if you follow what I suggest.

Comment: I will attempt your method and get back to you asap. it appears i was massively overthinking this, then?

Comment: i believe i have it figured out, except for our to get R_1 instead of R_2 in the numerator

Comment: @RobJeffries could you check if my differentiation is correct? I'm sorry if this seems simple to you, but I don't get it.

Comment: $V_{in}$ does not appear in your solution. Replace it.

Comment: as i don't want to clutter up SE with comments, Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20525/discussion-between-user57404-and-rob-jeffries). @RobJeffries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let put $V_{in}$ in this way:

$$
V_{in}= \frac{R_1+R_2}{R_2}V_{out}
$$

Now, diferentiate the equation $V_{out}=V_{in} \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}$ :

$$
\delta V_{out}=V_{in}\delta \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}=V_{in}\left ( \frac{1}{R_1+R_2}- \frac{R_2}{(R_1+R_2)^2}  \right )\delta R_2= V_{in}\left ( \frac{R_1}{(R_1+R_2)^2} \right )\delta R_2 = V_{out} \frac{R_1+R_2}{R_2}\left ( \frac{R_1}{(R_1+R_2)^2} \right )\delta R_2 =  V_{out}\left ( \frac{R_1}{(R_1+R_2)} \right )\frac{\delta R_2}{R_2}
$$

Now we have: $$\frac{\delta V_{out}}{V_{out}}=\frac{\delta R_2}{R_2} \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}$$

Comment: how do you go from V_in( 1/(R1+R2).... to the next step, where its' just V_in(R1/(R1+R2)^2 ? I don't understand that part. But thanks, perfect!

Comment: I made $\frac{1}{R_1+R_2} = \frac{R_1+R_2}{(R_1+R_2)^2}$

Comment: [Please do not give full solutions to homework problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange/715#715).

Comment: I can't delete this aswering.